# Javascript: Only using specific parameter in function

Tags: javascript, function-parameter

I think it is rather a beginner's question: How can I address a specific parameter in a function and ignore the others?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8QuWj/

```
function test(para_1, para_2, para_3) {
   if (para_3 == true) {
    alert('only the third parameter was successfully set!');
   }
}

test(para_3=true);
```

I want to individually decide whether or not I use a certain parameter in a function or not.

Comment: Pass a hash map to the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check each parameter separately using an `if(param)`, like:

```
function test(para_1, para_2, para_3) {
    if (para_1) {
        // First parameter set
    }
    if (para_2) {
        // Second parameter set
    }
    if (para_3) {
        // Third parameter set
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, you **cannot** set only one parameter and expect it to be the third, because it will automatically set it to the first one, and the remaining 2 as `undefined`. So if you would like to call your function and only have the third set, most probably you'd do a

```
test(null, null, 'this_is_set');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in JavaScript to pass named arguments. The best you can do is to accept an object as a single parameter, and from there, you decide which properties to set.

```
function test(obj) {
   if (obj.para_3 == true) {
    alert('only the third parameter was successfully set!');
   }
}

test({para_3:true});
```

Comment: This is incorrect; you can assert the parameter doesn't equals undefined.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye what part is incorrect?  I think this answer is the best fit to what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Segfault - The OP wants to determine if the parameter 'para3' was passed. Scimonster says this isn't possible, but it *is* - you can check if para3 === undefined. Whilst the map argument approach is more flexible and more readable for multiple optional parameters, it is not, as the answer suggests, the only option the language provides.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye I changed my answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply Arguments stored in an array. The entrys of the argument array will be mapped to the paramters of the function.

```
var arg = [];
arg[2] = true;
test.apply(this, arg);
```

the other way is to just set the other params to undefined:

```
test(undefined, undefined, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QuWj/2/